# Listen to onSetStatus event

Tags: plugin-development, entry, services, status

I wanted to listen to the `onSetStatus` event of the `SetStatusElementAction` and used the same code like in the `EntryElementType` class:

```
$setStatusAction = craft()->elements->getAction('SetStatus');
$setStatusAction->onSetStatus = function(Event $event) {
  MyPlugin::log('maybe');
}
```

But it didn't work and I had to hack into the core making following code changes:

in the `ElementsService` class:

```
/**
 * Fires an 'onSetStatus' event.
 *
 * @param Event $event
 *
 * @return null
 */
public function onSetStatus(Event $event)
{
    $this->raiseEvent('onSetStatus', $event);
}
```

in the `EntryElementType::getAvailableActions` method where the `onSetStatus` is called:

```
craft()->elements->onSetStatus($event);
```

This way I'm able to listen to the event in my plugin:

```
craft()->on('elements.setStatus', function() { ... });
```

The problem is that with the next update I have to do the code changes again. Is there a better way to listen to the event or is this worth a push request?

Comment: Craft 2.5.2750 seems to have introduced the `elements.onPerformAction` and `elements.onBeforePerformAction` events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered, you should be using the more generic [elements.onBeforePerformAction](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#elements-onBeforePerformAction) or [elements.onPerformAction](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#elements-onPerformAction) events.  They get fired when *any* action takes place and you can check their `action` parameter to determine if it was a `SetStatus` action.